# AWS Lambda + API Gateway causes 500 error on throttle

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function which works well using the API as long as the invoking API request does not get throttled. But as soon as throttling begins some of the requests fail with 500 error (Internal Server Error). What could be causing this. It cannot be the code as it works perfectly as long as the function is not being throttled (Verified as I decreased concurrency, the number of 500s increased drastically). Any pointers would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda rejects direct requests to functions that are currently throttled. If you need them to queue rather than being dropped when a function is throttled, which is the same situation I'm in with a current project, one solution is to have your Lambda function [consume from an SNS topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html). You can then use boto3 or whatever other method you'd like to add messages to the topic, which Lambda will consume until they're gone at its set throttle rate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just needed some clarification